# QGIS unable to connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, qgis

I am trying to connect `QGis` to remote MySQL server (v. 5.0.95) and this is the error I get:

```
 Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused
 (client option 'secure_auth' enabled) QMYSQL: Unable to connect
```

I saw that there are similar problems for people using different tools, which are resolved but options in those tools, but in `Qgis` I don't have any other connection options.

If needed, some intervention on MySQL server is very much possible.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and here's the solution, run this query

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0;
SET PASSWORD FOR 'user-name'@'%' = PASSWORD('123456');
```

where user-name is your userename, % is host name (if exisitng, else leave %). Of coruse, change 123456 with your password.